# Python Stereographic Projection

Tags: python

I have recently been interested in replicating a stereographic projection using the Manim library. After examining existing [code](https://github.com/3b1b/videos/blob/master/_2018/quaternions.py) that was provided in a 3Blue1Brown video, I became confused with the calculation of a stereographic projection of a point. Neglecting the normalization code at the end of the method, I am confused as to how the quotient is being calculated. From [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stereographic_projection), my expectation for the formula appears to disagree with what was written in the code.

[image: \left(\frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z}\right) \ne \left(\frac{x \cdot r}{z + r}, \frac{y \cdot r}{z+r}\right)]

```
 def stereo_project_point(point, axis=2, r=1, max_norm=10000):
    point = fdiv(point * r, point[axis] + r)
    point[axis] = 0
    norm = get_norm(point)
    if norm > max_norm:
        point *= max_norm / norm
    return point
```

Comment: "From Wikipedia, my expectation for the formula appears to disagree with what was written in the code." What is your expectation for the formula? Is the code shown what you wrote yourself or what you found on YouTube? Either way, provide the other one for comparison.

Comment: I suspect the difference is a simple matter of the point of view -- whether `z` gets larger coming at you, or gets smaller coming at you.  Modulo that, I think the two formulae are indentical.

Comment: I'm primarily confused with the multiplication by r in the numerator as the denominator may be addressed with a linear change of variables. My expectation for the formula is ((x/(1-z)), (y/(1-z))), and I took the code from Grant Sanderson's (3Blue1Browns) Github repository.